# Deserialize at construction

Tags: java

I have a class that implements `Serializable`. I have a method in it that serializes itself:

```
...
fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
out.writeObject(this);  
...
```

And I want to deserialize it when I call the constructor. Is that possible? I've tried several things but they didn't work.

For instance, I've tried:

```
...
fis = new FileInputStream(path);
in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
this = (MySerializableClass)in.readObject();
...
```

But, of course, `this` is not a variable that you can assign like that...

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this as such, but you can deserialize the object which is of the same type and copy all the values to the current object.

A common approach is to not serialise the object itself but all the data need to reload it.

Comment: Could you detail why it's not common to serialize the object itself? I didn't understand what you meant. Thanks.

Comment: If you are serializing externally to the object, you would serialize the object because you also expect to deserialize the object.  If the object is serializing or deserializing itself, it would only serialise its own fields.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization mechanism usually bypasses constructor. If you need constructor invoked, you can use [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) instead. This article shortly stresses differences between Serializable and Externalizable: http://javapapers.com/core-java/externalizable-vs-serializable/

Answer (score 0):

Main concept of `UnSerializaion` is that it never calls `Constructor` rather you manually copy values to the object from `steam`.

When an instance of a `serializable` class is deserialized, the `constructor` does not run, and `instance variables`
are NOT given their initially assigned values.

***De-Serialization in Constructor is not possible.***

Comment: Do you mean that I only can unserialize from where the serializable class is instantiated?

Comment: No, You can read stream from anywhere in class except constructor and then cast them .

Answer (score 0):

How can you assign `this` to `(double[])`?

You can not do it However you can assign values inside constructor to object's fields You can use same method ie. `readObject()` or `readInt()` etc.

e.g.

```
this.doubleArray = (double[])in.readObject();
```

Comment: But I have to deserialize the whole object to an auxiliar one and then copy its fields, right? Smoething like this:
`MySerializableClass aux = (MySerializableClass) in.readObject();`
`this.field1 = aux.field1;`
`...`
The way you say you're assuming that my class is a `double[]`.

Comment: No that is not needed once you deserialize it it will have all the field values assigned to it provided it does not contain any Non serializable members. So `MySerializableClass aux = (MySerializableClass) in.readObject();` is what you need to do there is no need to use constructor then `aux` object will have values assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to deal with this scenario is to create a Factory type static method to return an instance of the class (via serialization) instead of trying to do it via the constructor...so your client code would do something like...

```
MySerializableClass myClass = MySerializableClass.Create(path);
```

(where Create is your static method)

Comment: Yes, finally I did it through a static method rather than the constructor. But quite different to your solution. It was called from the client as: `MySerializableClass myClass = new MySerializableClass(); myClass.create(path);`

Comment: That's not a static method, that's an instance method.